# Possible to view more options in helm-bibtex?

Tags: helm, bibtex

When I use helm-bibtex, I get a screen showing some of the properties of the articles in my .bib file. For example, I get some sort of table where the columns are

```
|author | title | year | articletype|
```

I was wondering if I could edit this so that I could remove the last column and replace it with some other property of my choosing, such as a tags property.

Answer (score 1):

Not by default, as those column headings are wired into the code of `bibtex-completion-candidates-formatter`.

However, you can use the `org-ref` package, which redefines that function to display the keywords for each entry.

Comment: I have org-ref installed, but I don't know how to do this. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @theQman `(require 'org-ref)` then use the function `org-ref-set-bibtex-keywords` to add keywords to the current bibtex entry in your bib file. Then those keywords will show up in the `helm-bibtex` display. Does that help?

Comment: This information is outdated.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable `bibtex-completion-display-format` to configure the layout of the table to your liking.  You can even define different columns depending on the entry type (article, proceedings, ...).  Below is the layout that I'm using:

```
(setq bibtex-completion-display-formats
    '((article       . "${author:36} ${title:*} ${journal:40} ${year:4} ${=has-pdf=:1}${=has-note=:1} ${=type=:3}")
      (inbook        . "${author:36} ${title:*} Chapter ${chapter:32} ${year:4} ${=has-pdf=:1}${=has-note=:1} ${=type=:3}")
      (incollection  . "${author:36} ${title:*} ${booktitle:40} ${year:4} ${=has-pdf=:1}${=has-note=:1} ${=type=:3}")
      (inproceedings . "${author:36} ${title:*} ${booktitle:40} ${year:4} ${=has-pdf=:1}${=has-note=:1} ${=type=:3}")
      (t             . "${author:36} ${title:*} ${year:4} ${=has-pdf=:1}${=has-note=:1} ${=type=:3}")))
```